Styling geoJSON points when adding data
I have a leaflet map where I show some simple geoJSON point markers. Because I'm loading them from external .geojson files, I'm using this function:
        async function addPointGeoJson(layername, filename, style={}) {
            const response = await fetch(filename);
            const data = await response.json();
            layername.addData(data, {
                pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.circleMarker(latlng, style);
                }
            });
        };

Then I'm adding a layer with the .geojson data as follows:
        let markers = L.geoJSON();
        addPointGeoJson(markers, "markers.geojson", markerStyle)

I'm trying to get the markers to get styled according to this option object:
        let markerStyle = {
            radius: 1,
            fillColor: "#000",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        };

Currently, my markers appear but in the default styling instead of the provided styling. There are no errors of any kind.
I've taken a look at several other threads online and tried to work out where I'm wrong. I feel like perhaps the .addData method doesn't allow an options object, but I'm having a hard time figuring out if that's the problem. All the online examples are styling the points when the layer is created, but I want to do it when data is added to the layer.
Relevant docs:
https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson
https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-adddata
Some threads:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75590/setstyle-function-for-geojson-features-leaflet
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282665/layer-adddata-circle-marker-style-pointtolayer

The issue stems from how Leaflet's GeoJSON layer and the addData method work together. When you create a GeoJSON layer with L.geoJSON(), any options need to be specified at creation time. The addData method is primarily for adding new GeoJSON data to an existing layer, but it doesn't accept styling options directly.


async function addPointGeoJson(filename, style = {}) {
    // First, fetch and parse the GeoJSON data
    const response = await fetch(filename);
    const data = await response.json();
    
    // Create the GeoJSON layer with styling options
    // Note: We create the layer after we have the data
    const layer = L.geoJSON(data, {
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            return L.circleMarker(latlng, style);
        }
    });
    
    return layer;
}

// Usage:
let markerStyle = {
    radius: 1,
    fillColor: "#000",
    color: "#000",
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.8
};

// Since we're using async/await, we need to handle this asynchronously
async function initializeMap() {
    let markers = await addPointGeoJson("markers.geojson", markerStyle);
    markers.addTo(map);  // Add the styled layer to the map
}

initializeMap();



If you need to maintain a reference to the layer before the data is loaded (for example, to add/remove it from the map later), you could modify the approach like this:


// Create the layer first but with styling options
let markers = L.geoJSON(null, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, markerStyle);
    }
});

// Then add the data when it's available
async function loadMarkers() {
    const response = await fetch("markers.geojson");
    const data = await response.json();
    markers.addData(data);
}

// Add the layer to the map immediately (it will be empty until data loads)
markers.addTo(map);
loadMarkers();



